# How can I resume session with the aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-session-manager

I've started a session with the command
`aws ssm start-session --target <instance id> --region <my region>`, and when I do that I get `Starting session with SessionId <sessionid>` and am logged into the ec2 instance. I then left my computer and the connection timed out. Now I want to return to that session.

I tried the command
`aws ssm resume-session --session-id <sessionid from above> --region <my region>` which returns something like
`{ "SessionId": "<sessionid from above>", "TokenValue": "", "StreamUrl": "<url here>" }` . But how do I actually connect again? That leaves me on my local computer, whereas the `start session` command puts me on the aws instance. If I try the start-session command again, I get a brand new session. I feel like I am missing something obvious!

Comment: What `status` do you see when you execute `describe-sessions` ?

Comment: I see a list of sessions that includes the new session id I got when I tried start-session again with status 'Connected', not the old session id that I want to reconnect to though.

Answer (score 1):

as the aws cli docs state you'll need to be sure that you've configured the following:

> Note that this interactive command requires the Session Manager plugin
> to be installed on the client machine making the call.

For more information, see Install the Session Manager Plugin for the AWS CLI in the AWS Systems Manager User Guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html

Also please be aware of the following:

> ResumeSession, Reconnects a session to an instance after it has been disconnected.
> Connections can be resumed for disconnected sessions, but not
> terminated sessions. This command is primarily for use by client machines to automatically reconnect during intermittent network issues. It is not intended for any other use
>
> You can use the AWS Systems Manager console or the AWS Command Line
> Interface (AWS CLI) to end a session that you started to connect to an
> instance in your account. If there is no user activity after 20
> minutes, a session is ended. After a session is ended, it can't be
> resumed.

anyhoo, I've you started a session and timeout/disconnect the resume session command will provide you with a new instance that you can immediately use as per the docs:

> This resume-session example resumes a Session Manager session with an
> instance after it has been disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to resume a session:

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/resume-session.html

> This command is primarily for use by client machines to automatically reconnect during intermittent network issues. It isn’t intended for any other use.